# Generate a valid array key from an URL string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a PHP array with some predefined values:

```
$aArray = array(
    0 => 'value0',
    1 => 'value1'
);
```

I need to create a function where the string input will always return the same, valid, array key so that when I call:

```
GiveMeAKey('http://www.google.com');  // May return 0 or 1
```

I receive always the same key (I don't care which one) from the array. Obvisously I can't store the relationship in a database and the string passed to the GiveMeAKey method can be any URL.

I wonder if there is a way of doing that ?

Comment: Are you talking about just getting a hash to identify the URL by?

Comment: If you don't care: `function GiveMyAKey($url) { return 0;}` ;o)

Comment: @coreyward: yes this is a hash but it must be a numeric value representing a key from an array which I do not control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate something random from the input string and choose a key based on that:

```
function GiveMeAKey($str, array $array) {
    return $array[crc32($str) % count($array)];
}
```

Example:

```
echo GiveMeAKey("http://www.google.com/", $aArray);    //value0
echo GiveMeAKey("http://www.altavista.com/", $aArray); //value1
```

NOTE: CRC32 is not a good hash function, but has the nice property it returns a 32-bit number you can use with the `%` operator. But for your purposes, it suffices.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a [Hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to a hash function, could be something like calculating the ASCII sum of the string and then return it in modulo 2.

Comment: @poke Well. A hash function I probably will never use.